# Start script running in graphical environment from user B while graphical environment has been created by user A

Tags: linux, environment-variables, vnc

I am working on a Linux Debian server. 
In order to run a specific application I had to create a graphical environment with vnc4server, that is initiated on boot with *user A*.

In order to start my script, i normally have to do:

```
export DISPLAY=:1.0
```

then run my script

Now I need to be able to start my script from another *user B*.
If i run it i receive error `Can't connect to X11 window server using ':1.0' as the value of the DISPLAY variable.`

I tried setting the display variable to `DISPLAY=:1.0` or `DISPLAY=:1` but i am not familiar with VNC and still receive the same error.

How should i configure *user B* DISPLAY variable so that my script can run in it as well?

Answer (score 0):

Exactly as you already have.

The problem is that user B [is not authorized](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Window_authorization) to have their clients connect to the server. Either have user A run `xhost` appropriately to allow access, or have user A share their magic cookie with user B. See the `xhost(1)` and `xauth(1)` man pages for details.

Comment: o thx for the hint. I tried to add user B to the list of accepted host by running xhost userB, but it returns `xhost:  bad hostname "userB"` . What is a host exatly? it is not the same as a user? I read both man pages for xhost and xauth, but for a newb its not clear at all what is the simplest way to solve that problem

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Host_(network)

Comment: if you know how to add another user to the xhost please let me know the command to use. Otherwise thx anyway the links are interesting.